# Selecting N rows in R using Sparklyr

Tags: r, sparklyr

I'm trying to select distinct middle rows of SparkDataframe using Sparklyr.

I've been looking for it and I have not found it (only *head* and *tail* functions but I don't want these). Is there a sparklyr function that makes the same as traditional R playing with dimensions of dataframe?
I need to create a R dataframe with n:m rows of a SparkDataframe.

For example, if n=1 and m=5:

**Traditional R**

```
data(iris)

iris2 <- iris[1 : 5, ]
```

**Sparklyr**

```
sc <- spark_connect(master = "local")
iris_tbl <- sdf_copy_to(sc, iris, name = "iris", overwrite = TRUE)
```

Tips: I was reviewing *slice()* but an errors ocurrs when I code:

```
iris2 <- iris_tbl %>% slice(1:5) %>% collect()

no applicable method for 'slice' applied to an object of class "c('tbl_spark', 'tbl_sql', 'tbl_lazy', 'tbl')"
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Make an index column and then filter out the upper and lower indices. So if I want to keep 5:7 I do:

```
iris_tbl <- sdf_copy_to(sc, iris, name = "iris", overwrite = TRUE) %>%
  sdf_with_sequential_id(id = "index") %>%
  filter(5<=index, index<=7)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: @strawberryBeef Please note that this should be used with extreme caution. It not triggers additional action on the input, which might be a problem as such, is quite expensive due to `Dataset` -> `RDD` -> `Dataset` conversion, but also assumes that table has deterministic order, which might, or might be not the case, depending on the upstream process.

Comment: @zero323 Could you elaborate on that comment? [The documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/sparklyr/versions/1.1.0/topics/sdf_with_sequential_id) mentions that function uses [`zipWithIndex`](http://allaboutscala.com/tutorials/chapter-8-beginner-tutorial-using-scala-collection-functions/scala-zipwithindex-example/) Scala function; I would hope that it works on similar basis as the remaining `sdf_*` functions offered via sparklyr. I would like to understand it better as `dataset` -> `RDD` -> `dataset` conversion would disastrous on datasets I want to handle through this solution.